# Rotate UIImageView inside UIScrollView issue

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, rotation

I have to implement the rotate works like the photo app. Having the `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView`. and when device rotate, I want the image to rotate to landscape like Photo's. If the image is landscape-one, then it will fill the whole `UIScrollView`'s width with the rotation animation. When the following code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.36
               animations:^(void){
                [_imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*90/180)];
                 _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320); //set the frame after the rotate
                self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480, 320); //set the content-size of the scrollview
               }
               completion:^(BOOL complete){
               }];
```

But this does not work. rotate happens, but the position of the `_imageView` is not correct, or the image did not fill the width. Even I change the order frame and content-size before transform, still not correct.

What will be the correct approach to have this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer, in my opinion, is to not animate the rotation yourself at all.

If you work according to the latest `iOS 6` guidelines, then you just rearrange your `views` in the `ViewController` its `layoutSubviews()` method.

Comment: The problem is the rotate will not happen in my view-controller(intend to), the UIScrollView is a popup subview which contains the UIImageView with black-background. only want to rotate the UIImageView, but the view-controller's whole view.

Comment: Why don't you want to rotate the view controller?

Comment: I am using the uitabview-controller, and in one of the view-controller, I have a tableview, if the table-cell has an image, it will be popover when clicked. so I only want to rotate the pop-over image, not the whole uitabview-controller.

Comment: Yep. I've already solved the problem. I was doing everything right. I just had to add this statement to my code: myScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Answer (score 1):

The [WWDC 2010 Video: Designing Apps with Scrolls Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) shows you exactly how to do this.

Comment: I was looking for how this would help a layout change problem I was having. They didn't discuss layout change at all.

Comment: @RameezHussain - They might not have talked exactly about it in the video, but it's all in the code that comes with the video. They show you how to make that imageView in the UIScrollView so that it centers and stays within the bounds after you pan and scale it. Also, when you rotate it, if the UIImageView's height and width is smaller than the superviews bounds, it'll scale it to fit as big as it can in the new bounds.

Comment: I found the answer from the suggested video. But since there's a limit on the comment size, I've added another answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The source code that @CoDEFRo refers to is similar to the following, but here I've put it into the UIScrollView's delegate method scrollViewDidScroll:.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {   
    CGSize boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size;
    CGRect frameToCenter = self.imageView.frame;

    if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width)
        frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
    else
        frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;

    if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height)
        frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
    else
        frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;

    self.imageView.frame = frameToCenter;
}
```